# Pass component with arbirtrary/generic props to react-redux connect function in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, react-redux

I'm trying to connect a React element with `react-redux` that has arbitrary/generic props, but it's not compiling correctly. I've tried using `JSXElementConstructor` and `(new (props: Props) => React.Component<Props, any>)` instead of `ComponentType`, but got a different error about how `Props` could be instantiated with a different type. Here's the code. Any help would be appreciated.

https://github.com/piotrwitek/react-redux-typescript-guide/issues/55 looks related, but that seems to be about the props having a generic, instead of the props themselves being a generic.

**Code**

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

interface StoreState {
  someState: number;
}

// Tried `React.JSXElementConstructor<Pros>`
// and `(new (props: Props) => React.Component<Props, any>)`
// instead of `React.ComponentType<Props>`, but got a different error.
function createWrapperComponent<Props>(
  componentElement: React.ReactElement<
    Props,
    React.ComponentType<Props> & { update(props: Props): void }
  >
) {
  const props = componentElement.props;
  const UnconnectedComponent = componentElement.type;
  const ConnectedComponent = connect<StoreState, {}, Props, StoreState>(
    (state) => state
  )(UnconnectedComponent);

  return class WrapperComponent extends React.Component<any> {
    static update = UnconnectedComponent.update;
    render() {
      return <ConnectedComponent {...props} />;
    }
  };
}
```

**Playground Link:** [Provided](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wG4AoUSWOAbzjQgDsmkM4BfObXAo9GAFoiAEwCuADzLlKTGEiiZ0SOAGUY0JOpTy65OHADOuLTB1IAXHCZiQAIwUUOMgPQu4AFSjAkIuAANkAQA6AClVAA0AUQAbJBAkOQBhZkMYKDEMaH84FCY-fwAKVgB3OEKwHDBDKwAFKsMASjgAXgA+RGIYYJTwZkSYAB56iGqAGlymAE82xv9yNzhgJjTUPwhMAKCMHtxIVjkPKbAkfwm7MXgAcwh4FDgRYExMBQG4BRwoYPJMMSYMYDMBj8eS9fYDYYNNqFfQMPb9OSxeIDKzbbpopEJOSDWEGEbjXGdEJghEwI4nSGjQwdABkdDgYjAInMFQadQajSsADcIMA-M4DG1yM1aLDGCt4JUqa04X0DjBMQNglLqhQDOK0nAAKr-ZisDC+EnymWMOUDRVyYIwY5INVwiVwFIsNjyERGt4te36obqTTaeQTWgcCb4wwTX1Ef1IaGEwppczNdpGMzyWGNQo68Xew3w+WNCiwogwMRQJgMGIoQyGOAAdSgKDAJyg7rk7wk8ny1bRuzN2LyMz0BgM8ZgwDQDKZ5hlmb1Lpzve6jOZ8jtBiI+QUhRFhLXSGLpbggyd2bdubetGCl5Vhi4Ljaq84sI4TnIQA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: [Here's](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?jsx=2&ssl=16&ssc=59&pln=16&pc=54#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecDCANigM4kCCMMUwARgK4xInZGkkAqAnmEtsuhgA5CABM+BCOAgA7JDKyTpchQGUYKJqymQVMNmTgBfOADMoUuACIoqDFYDcAKFCRYuOGllyM2ACLAJGCaaAAWAAoWYNgA4kgwkRBgLHAAsiGhwDIA5sZmFiDWtoIAtLai9AAejk4uCkhQpuhIcOrQSOqaLThOcHAkUh0aTABccDL0ILQNzka1MDwtAJIyAFZIGEiiiclwALytMO2dTHAAZHABQRk7zk6m9DIYwLKexUz4OrLyMAA8vXAdiwAfg4EhKkwZKISIg7DAAHSfZQ-bi8X7pGBhLLZX4rdabbZRFJxBJE374AB8VPOHnoYFEXQAFGAiWMgQBKMYANwgwFExicFMZXmRCgAooQkCAfmMBBh4XKYBKpT9fkDWBT2bgAV4ZCR4CykjCDiLdD9ldKFPDDclnH1dfq4ABVJ7eDZMURIs0KfaeL56C0-eELXh2v16+CfGQ+D1e74+k1ujC-Nq2E4SHBGbDqw7HYZIIUAvqM-VdLV7Cn9fMA9mMl26mNbON6dl3Pq2GD0KAyTzEQwAdSgKDAvCgzZ+YIh8mhsMEiP9qpQMi4lZ6fT6pZgwDQcDpDNOB3rSdjC6te66Yfb04ajK1a-XV873bg5OPTdP8Bw8O-NpIJgA9BSl4Cn0RizLUaB9jCoLgpCM6KvOop-HgTD6mMExTA0xirgCm7bru9JMr+YwocwMDoZM0xQMYd4CnMDxPFurxoO8SCBgoarYBwk5wdBH6cUo3owOmFKsDx058UhBgkGqVKMiGSBjNJqJIAJHAatgv4APxKVBlDUHQjDML8HCVhc4RwAAPuM9CEIQ2DfvCWKEKItgyLKcIiOIADaAC67JOPeHZdj2CEsagTDsTA8mLJpRLYM5rnyFqpCzvKipRQJlLgVyKDUUgkqWvAJqsVFjL4NgpFoXAADMNHOOFXTjgojIFSqCitk4QA) an approach that avoids the initial cast to `any`. Now I'm casting the props passed to `ConnectedComponent` instead. Investigating the type issue there might reveal whether there are more potential issues than the one I mentioned.

---

What you're doing is not sound. If `Props` were `{ someState: string }`, your `UnconnectedComponent` would be expecting its `someState` prop to be a `string`, but it would be a `number`.

If `stateProps` and `dispatchProps` should override `ownProps`, which is what your code is doing now, I'm not sure whether you're going to be able to get the types to work automatically the way you want. TypeScript can't figure out that the following is sound:

```
function a<Props>(
  b: { [K in keyof Props]: K extends keyof StoreState ? StoreState[K] : Props[K] }
): Omit<Props, keyof StoreState>
{
  return b;
}
```

Maybe you should bite the bullet and use `any`. [Here's](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?jsx=2#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-Y1WwwehQGSeYiGADqUBQYF4UEjejgSHSTBkolmMseg4UpxQY+uVRqNQ7wDQcGxuNWC17TqBW99T4qgan8nEUB4mq143n+M5znASLvhGp7wDg9wIeaJAmAA9Jcv7GBqRjdNkaCLrM+A7nu-5HncJ4CtmeAIjALRtB0eTYHUYpJi02o0DIADmxhXhqd4Pt+TAEkSHjUbR7SdFAjH1CxtTUMAnHGMBmE9PSjIwMy85oGySA+me4TYBwRH7oeSjutm+mmVGMBJpcrBGSRll6NC5zoni-otNCyoGawtlwEhAD8Hn4ZQcnwswpwcGCcDhHAAA+rT0IQhDYAh9xhMAhCiLYMgSncIjiAA2gAuiSTggdOs7zseWmoEwukwG5-TYEh2DpZl2VqiOx4yvV5w+Th5JfDuIomvAMbafVeL4NgVHMDRcAAMxScxjRIC0ADk62Kc4NUVJ+Ch4kgI2vBOThAA) a sample of how you might try to make the caller-facing types safer.

If you instead want `ownProps` to override `stateProps`, you would want to provide a `mergeProps` argument to `connect`.

However, be warned that when you create a `ReactElement` via JSX, the `type` field has type `any`, which of course won't give you type safety if you then call `createComponent`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Props` doesn't refer to any types defined. So I guess leave it blank is ok?

```
function createComponent(componentElement: React.ReactElement<{}, React.ComponentType>) {
  const props = componentElement.props;
  const UnconnectedComponent = componentElement.type;
  const ConnectedComponent = connect<StoreState, {}, {}, StoreState>(state => state)(UnconnectedComponent);

  return <ConnectedComponent {...props} />
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I do actually use the `Props` generic elsewhere, I just didn't include it at first to try to keep it simple. I've updated my question to include the other place where I use the `Props` generic.